# Correct description of tags

Tags: support, tags

Few days ago, I created a tag [disaster-management](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disaster-management). I added excerpt and details. Following which a learned user of our community [**rejected**](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/44786), while two other users **accepted** the edit. It is live now. It is as it is as I added, which is

> Question relating to policies, etc. on disaster management.

The reason to reject was legit. It is a prescribed reject reason by Stack Exchange.

> Tag excerpts amounting to, "[tag] is for questions about [tag]" are pointless and usually rejected. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag would be used.

Looking at the other tags of our site, say [ukraine](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ukraine), I see similar description.

> Questions relating to the government or the politics of Ukraine.

I think every country tag has similar description.

I am not here to attack the learned user who rejected my edit, instead I am here to ask, what else may I or people here may add to describe a country tag or topic tags like disaster-management?

Comment: Tags are also used to help group questions by what they are about and sometimes the description you are showing is the best one available. What else would you suggest for a tag to describe a question that is about Ukraine or the politics of disaster management?

Comment: @JoeW I can't think of think of anything else. As you can see many of our tags fall into the category of the said reject reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Usually*" doesn't mean "always."  I know that this is stating the obvious.  But in this case

> Tag excerpts amounting to, "[tag] is for questions about [tag]" are pointless and **usually** rejected. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag would be used.

doesn't mean that they must always be rejected.  I think that the 2 people who agreed with your description were probably right.  But not without reason.

"X is for labeling X" is not a very good description, but not everything needs a good description.

If there a chance of ambiguity, then excerpt presents and opportunity to disambiguate and to make it clear what is the use of the tag on this site.  But when the tag leaves little room for misinterpretation, then "X is for tagging X" is actually enough.

It's possible that the one person who disagreed with your description did have a use case in mind which may make the use you suggested counterintuitive.  I really can't tell.  It's ok to trust the human element when it comes to voting.  It's what voting is for.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the [disaster-management](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disaster-management) tag is not needed, at all.

The [sole question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/75416/26455) with that tag refers to the [Coalition for Disaster Resilient Infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalition_for_Disaster_Resilient_Infrastructure), whose stated purpose is:

> Promote the resilience of new and existing infrastructure systems to climate and disaster risks, thereby ensuring sustainable development.

Thus, the existing [infrastructure](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure) and [sustainable-development](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustainable-development) tags are sufficient to describe what the coalition and question is about.

---

What about the [disaster-management](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disaster-management) tag?

Narrowly, *disaster management* is what occurs *after* a disaster. Alternatively, *disaster risk management* occurs *before* a disaster (or before the next similar disaster). This suggests that the tag probably should have been [disaster-risk-management](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disaster-risk-management) for which the excerpt could have been:

> Questions about mitigating the risks of potential physical disasters, such as earthquakes, flooding, drought, etc.

---

Specifically, for country tags, when I have added excerpts, I have included the geographic area for the location of the country or other identifying information.

For example,

- [mali](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mali) : Questions relating to the government or politics of the Republic of Mali a landlocked country in West Africa.
- [somaliland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/somaliland) : Questions about the Republic of Somaliland, an unrecognized sovereign state internationally considered to be part of Somalia.

When the Republic of Turkey officially changed its name, I changed the excerpt.

- [turkey](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turkey) : Questions relating to the government or politics of the Republic of Türkiye. Formerly and commonly known as Turkey.

For those countries that are well-known, the "government of politics of" is sufficient.

---

For tag excerpts, generally, there are, as of this writing, 801 active tags (not including synonyms). *See*, the first comment at [Is there a way to export the list of tags as plain text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345074/is-there-a-way-to-export-the-list-of-tags-as-plain-text) for a means to access the current list of tags.

Approximately 100 Politics SE tags have no excerpts (requires some spreadsheet manipulation or hand counting).

Comment: While I agree I could have used infrastructure tag (at that moment I couldn't find it), your answer doesn't answer my question. I asked what could be the correct description of tags (for countries), which you didn't answer.

Comment: From [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info), I am getting 107 tags where the post for wiki/excerpt is NULL: https://data.stackexchange.com/politics/query/1642472/tags-without-a-tag-excerpt and https://data.stackexchange.com/politics/query/1642470/tags-without-a-tag-wiki. And there are a few where the post for the tag-excerpt was created [but it is empty](https://data.stackexchange.com/politics/query/1642473/tags-with-empty-tag-excerpt). (As expected, a situation like this is [more usual for tag-wikis](https://data.stackexchange.com/politics/query/1642474/).)

Comment: The situations where the tag has a post for tag-excerpt, but it is empty, is usually result [of a rejected edit](https://data.stackexchange.com/politics/query/1626638/rejected-edits-on-tag-info-where-tag-tag-excerpt-tag-wiki-is-still-empty).