# How do I delete the tag disaster-management?

Tags: support, tags

As I have been correctly pointed out that an existing tag was sufficient for one of my questions [here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6351/34768), I have edited the question to add [infrastructure](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure) and removed [disaster-management](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disaster-management). I am thinking to delete the tag disaster-management but don't know how. Please provide me the solution.

Comment: I'm closing this question as a dupe - tags with no associated questions will be automatically deleted by a daily script.

Comment: @CDJB okay. That answers my question.